# MySQL beginner SQL statement outputs

Tags: mysql

I'm just learning MySQL and am working on determining the output of these statements by hand.

```
–SELECT * FROM transactions
WHERE txn_date < '2010-02-26' AND (txn_type_cd = 'debit' OR amount > 100.00)

–SELECT txn_id, txn_date, account_id
FROM transactions
WHERE account_id IN (1, 3) AND NOT (txn_type_cd = 'debit OR amount > 100.00)
```

[image: Here is the table I am working with]

[image: Here are the results that I came up with]

I just want to make sure I'm not making any mistakes before I move on. Thank you!

Comment: This may help: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/136c3/2

Comment: What is the issue????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You SQL Statement and you answer seem to match. However I will suggest using the Database name before accessing tables to run queries.
EG.

```
Use BankDB;

Select txn_id, txn_date
From
Transaction
```

Also I good idea is to always define the table columns you what to run queries on as * runs queries on all columns and increase execution time.
Some good books on my SQL:
https://createwebsite.pro/best-mysql-book/